# How do you modify one side in an SVG polygon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to change the color of one side of an SVG polygon.

I've tried with SVG lines, but it disconnects them.

Here's a codepen for ease: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJbowP

```css
.poly-line {
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#poly-line-c {
  stroke: red;
}

.triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
}
```

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
<line x1="150" y1="200" x2="30" y2="400" class="poly-line" id="poly-line-a"/>
<line x1="30" y1="400" x2="450" y2="400" class="poly-line" id="poly-line-b"/>
<line x1="150" y1="200" x2="450" y2="400" class="poly-line" id="poly-line-c"/>
</svg>

<svg height="500" width="500">
  <polygon points="150,200 30,400 450,400" class="triangle" />
</svg>
```

My question is simple. How do I make an SVG polygon where each side is modifiable?

Please leave a comment if more information is necessary.

Comment: Draw multiple polygons one on top of another and use stroke-dasharray to ensure only parts of each are drawn, or use lines/paths to draw the lines of the polygon separately.

Comment: you could try adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337615/1675954) to apply a gradient to one side? Also check out these [forum fiddles](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14743-multi-colored-lines-in-svg/?do=findComment&comment=63161) .. interesting!

Comment: The easiest fix to your problem is to add `.poly-line {stroke-linecap: round;}` to your first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to colour one edge of a `<polygon>` a different colour.

You can draw a line of a different colour on the top of the polygon.

```css
.poly-line {
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#poly-line-c {
  stroke: red;
}

.triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
}
```

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <polygon points="150,200 30,400 450,400" class="triangle" />
  <line x1="150" y1="200" x2="450" y2="400" class="poly-line" id="poly-line-c"/>
</svg>
```

Or if you want a less abrupt look, you could use a mask or clip to include the angled ends of the side.  But this requires a unique mask/clip for every side of every polygon that you want to be coloured differently.

In this example, I've used javascript to calculate the clip path polygon that is needed.

```js
// Calculates the "incentre" of the triangle.
// The incentre is the point where the three lines that bisect the three angles meet.
function calculateIncentre(ax,ay, bx,by, cx,cy)
{
  var aLen = Math.sqrt((bx-cx)*(bx-cx) + (by-cy)*(by-cy)); // length of line opposite point A
  var bLen = Math.sqrt((ax-cx)*(ax-cx) + (ay-cy)*(ay-cy)); // length of line opposite point B
  var cLen = Math.sqrt((bx-ax)*(bx-ax) + (by-ay)*(by-ay)); // length of line opposite point C
  var p = aLen + bLen + cLen;   // perimeter length of triangle
  return { x: (ax * aLen + bx * bLen + cx * cLen) / p,
           y: (ay * aLen + by * bLen + cy * cLen) / p }
}

//
// Generates a polygon that clips one side of a polygon.
// Make sure the side you care about is first (ie. ax,ay to bx,by)
//
function generateSideClipPolygon(ax,ay, bx,by, cx,cy)
{
  var incentre = calculateIncentre(ax,ay, bx,by, cx,cy);

  // If there is no stroke, you could use the following as the clip.
  //return [ax, ay, incentre.x,incentre.y, bx,by].join(',');
  
  // But since there is a stroke, we need to extend out clip polygon outwards a bit,
  // so that it includes/covers the outside half of the stroke.
  var extraFactor = 1.5;   // (you might need to increase this for larger stroke widths or sharper angles)
  // extend point A
  var dx = ax - incentre.x;
  var dy = ay - incentre.y;
  ax2 = incentre.x + dx * extraFactor;
  ay2 = incentre.y + dy * extraFactor;
  // extend point B
  var dx = bx - incentre.x;
  var dy = by - incentre.y;
  bx2 = incentre.x + dx * extraFactor;
  by2 = incentre.y + dy * extraFactor;
  return [ax2, ay2, incentre.x,incentre.y, bx2,by2].join(',');
}


document.getElementById("side-c").setAttribute("points", generateSideClipPolygon(450,400, 150,200, 30,400));
```

```css
.poly-line {
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#poly-line-c {
  stroke: red;
}

.triangle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #878787;
  stroke-width: 15;
}
```

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="side-c-clip">
      <polygon id="side-c" points=""/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <polygon points="150,200 30,400 450,400" class="triangle" />
  <polygon points="150,200 30,400 450,400" class="triangle" id="poly-line-c" clip-path="url(#side-c-clip)"/>
</svg>
```