# Is it possible to make the dots representing data points on a line graph have two colors (e.g. half red, half green, vertically split)?

Tags: d3.js

I have a fairly complex line chart with six different colored lines plotted on it and various data points marked by dots on the lines.

In some cases where there are many lines crossing over a small horizontal space, the chart can be difficult to read. To fix this, I would like to be able to make the dots incorporate the color of each line, e.g. if a green line and a red line cross, their point of intersection would be a dot whose left half is red and right half is green.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be with a linear gradient, as explained for a `<rect>` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335354/filling-an-svg-path-with-multiple-colors):

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="red-green" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="url(#red-green)" />
</svg>
```

For your purposes, it would be helpful to be able to set up the gradients programmatically with D3:

```js
const addGradient = (startColor, stopColor) => {
  const grad = defs.append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', `${startColor}-${stopColor}`)
    .attr('x1', '0%')
    .attr('y1', '0%')
    .attr('x2', '100%')
    .attr('y2', '0%')
        
  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .style('stop-color', startColor)
  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '50%')
    .style('stop-color', startColor)
  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '50%')
    .style('stop-color', stopColor)
  grad.append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .style('stop-color', stopColor)
}
    
const svg = d3.select('svg')
const defs = svg.append('defs')
addGradient('red', 'green')
    
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('cx', 50)
  .attr('cy', 50)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#red-green)')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100"></svg>
```